# Force High Quality Thumbnails for YouTube

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to force a high quality THUMBNAIL for YouTube?

My videos are of very high quality and once they start streaming they run fine in 720p, however the thumbnail for the video is of variable quality - sometimes it's high, other times it's really blurry.

Is there a way of forcing a high quality thumbnail? I've found this in the API docs - http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube%5Fdata%5Fapi%5Ftag%5Fmedia:thumbnail but it doesn't detail how to use the media tag.

Answer (score 22):

There is a "maxres" version as well, which is a "full hd" picture in case that the video resolution is high enough.

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg
```

However, if the video resolution isn't high enough, this image doesn't seem to be created. So you might want to have a function that shows a lower quality version in case the "maxres" version doesn't exist.

Check out [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api) for more info.

Comment: Hmm my video is 780p though and plays at high quality but the thumbnail quality is variable. The issue is not guessing the thumbnail, it's getting YouTube to display it below the 'play' symbol. Doesn't look like it's possible so far though.

Comment: I don't know what video or size you're using, but when i tried embedding another hd video, it seems to load the low-res picture if the video player object is too small. And when I embed the same video in a large player (i.e. 1000x700), i get the max-res version.

Comment: Thanks for the url. Is there a way I can force to use it in a embed video player?

Comment: I think the requirements are `&hd=1` in your iframe url and that the iframe must be larger than 1280x720 pixels, but I can't swear on it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, Johan for answer.

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg
```

If you also want set playback to HQ use Javascript API
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=fi-FI#Playback_quality

```
var qualityLevels = self.players[iframeID].getAvailableQualityLevels();
/* Set highest quality */
self.players[iframeID].setPlaybackQuality(qualityLevels[0]);
```

In order for this to work we first need to call:

```
self.players[iframeID].playVideo();
```

Then it will triggrer

```
self.players[iframeID] = new YT.Player(iframeID, {
                        events: {
                            'onReady': function(event) {
                                var iframe = $(event.target.getIframe());

                                self.players[iframe.attr('id')].loaded = true;
                            },
                            'onStateChange': function(event) {
                                var iframe = $(event.target.getIframe());
                                var iframeID = iframe.attr('id');

                                if(event.data == 1) /* playing */
                                {
                                    var qualityLevels = self.players[iframeID].getAvailableQualityLevels();

                                    if(self.players[iframeID].getPlaybackQuality() != qualityLevels[0])
                                    {
                                        /* Set highest quality */
                                        self.players[iframeID].setPlaybackQuality(qualityLevels[0]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/xjFouf6j81g/hqdefault.jpg
```

where xjFouf6j81g, videoid

Comment: Your response is the only one that worked for me, even throughout multiple threads.  Thank you.

Comment: Is that link part of the YouTube API V3 or below? Because if its from V2 or lower, then I'm pretty sure Google will be deprecating it?

Comment: @Dmitriy - See this: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=eb9de39901849211fd7fc42daabc6c0b . This json is for video Id: C2omic5yWRQ. It has maxresdefault.jpg has resolution 1280x720, compared to hqdefault.jpg having only 480x360.

Comment: @saurabheights which URL was this JSON requested from?

Comment: @agrath: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2omic5yWRQ. It's simple to make, open any youtube video and replace the value of v argument.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, YouTube only offers 4 thumbnails:

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/default.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/1.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/2.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/3.jpg
```

The thumbnails are generated once after the upload, so you can't alter the size of them in any way.

**Edit:**
YouTube JS API lets you force the quality of the video, but I don't know if it will affect the video preview. See [the docs](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_quality) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I apply them to the video, so that a high quality thumbnail is shown under the 'play' button?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been reported here:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=4590

Not a fix or a workaround, but if you want to avoid getting the low-res thumbnail your player should be larger than `430px` wide.

So a suggested minimum size for perfect 16:9 aspect would be `432 x 243 pixels` and this should get a nice-looking thumbnail.